# How to perform Ctrl+Alt+B when got cursor on a specific textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform with two text box. I have used key press events to move the cursor form one textbox to another textbox. when the specific textbox got the cursor then it perform "Ctrl+Alt+B" Key press. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call method [SendKeys.SendWait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netcore-3.1) to send keystroke. So perform `Ctrl+Alt+B` like

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^%B");
```

---

**Update:**

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(Byte bVk, Byte bScan, Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dwExtraInfo);

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Focus();

    keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(66, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0x2, 0);
    keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0x2, 0);
    keybd_event(66, 0, 0x2, 0);
}
```

For `bVk`, refer to [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).

Comment: Is Code ("^%B") For Ctrl+Alt+B, And Sign " for Ctrl, Sign  ^ for Alt?

Comment: You can refer to the document I provided. `^` is Ctrl, `%` is Alt.

Comment: I want to enable and disable a software by pressing Ctrl+Alt+B but this method is not work.

Comment: Simulate key input or capture key input? It seems that you want to capture Ctrl+Alt+B.

Comment: To enable a software i have to press Ctrl+Alt+B manually from my keyboard. But I want to enable that software by a key press event or double clicking on a text box event.

Comment: Maybe you can try to call [keybd_event function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event). I have updated the answer.

Comment: If this answers helps you, please click `√` mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks Your answer working but i don't understand key code. I understand first two lines is Ctrl and Alt but others lines not understand.

Comment: @DebKumer 66 is a decimal number, and the corresponding hexadecimal number is 0x42 (B key). And if  parameter `dwFlags` is `0x2`, the key will be released later.